# CurrentImage[] "unable to connect to camera"?

Tags: bugs, mac-os-x

I have a new Macbook Pro (Retina), running Mavericks.

For some reason I cannot access the camera in Mathematica using CurrentImage[] or ImageCapture[]. The result is:

```
CurrentImage::checkcam: Mathematica was unable to connect to a camera. Check 
that a camera is properly connected and that it is not currently in use 
by another application. >>
```

I do note that \$ImagingDevices is {}, and \$DefaultImagingDevice is None.

Any ideas?

Comment: Tried fixing disk permissions, and uninstall/reinstall, all to no luck.

Comment: I got word back from Wolfram, apparently a known problem, hopefully fixed in next release.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. This is the kind of information that is great to have, go ahead and write that as an answer if you want to.

Comment: @Pickett I'm not sure we should use the [tag:bugs] tag here, as there isn't a complete reproducible example in the question.  I have no problem using `CurrentImage` on a retina MacBook Pro running Mavericks.  It's not clear how the OP's setup differs from mine.  The tag would be appropriate if the OP at least makes it clear (based on the answer he received from WRI) in what situations the problem arises (and with what versions of Mma).  Otherwise the question is not really useful for future visitors trying to decide what's going wrong on their system ...

Comment: @Szabolcs I can't recreate this either with `CaptureImage` and Mavericks, but if I were having this problem I would definitely want to know that there is a confirmed bug. This bug has been confirmed by WRI, and confirmation as I understand it is enough to qualify for the bugs tag. But I may be wrong, that's just how I read the tag description.

Comment: Today I reinstalled Mathematica 9 on my MacBook Air 2013 - I had the external Apple Display connected when installing - now CurrentImage[] only works when external Display is connected and works through that camera. This may be a hint for others ...

Answer (score 7):

[ UPDATE 9/17/2014: I can confirm this problem is fixed in v10.0.1.0 ]

WRI has confirmed this as: "a known issue between Mathematica and the new 2013 Macbook". And says they are working on fixing it for the next major release.

FYI I'm running 2013 macbook w/ the discrete Nvidia card, & max memory, if that helps anyone who is trying to match my system.

I'll update when the problem goes away.